# Multiple schema connecting in a Springboot

Tags: spring-data-jpa, multiple-schema

I have one schema entity which is schema1.Test1. It has `test2Column` column as the **foreign key**.

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "schema1.Test1")

public class Test1 {
     @Id 
   
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;
    

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "test2Column ")
    private Test2 test2Column ;
}
```

test2Column belongs to schema2.Test2 table. While running the project I am getting below error:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.models.schema1.Test1.test2Column references an unknown entity: com.models.schema2.Test2 
at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:97) ~[hibernate-co**
```

Comment: It seems that you don't set the referencedColumnName inside the @JoinColumn annotation. Try to insert it like @JoinColumn(name = "test2Column ", referencedColumnName = "referencedColumnHere") where referencedColumnHere is the column referenced in Test2 class.

Comment: @JoinColumn(name = "test2Column", referencedColumnName = "test2Column") also it is giving same error

Comment: Could you update your question by adding the `Test2` entity?